# Understanding how T-SQL transactions are working

Tags: sql-server

I would like to understand deeply what is going on with my transactions:

I have a rule which executes each second 1 or 2 transactions (I receive a purchase event and I must save the purchased item and update the client balance). For simplicity let's call this `transaction A`.

On the other side a user can perform an action which trigger a stored procedure. This stored procedure contains a `transaction B` which operates on the same table of `transaction A`, but on different rows. Let's say `transaction B` make updates on last month purchases (could be thousand different rows), while `transaction A` is saving new purchases.

`transaction A` has a SERIALIZABLE ISOLATION LEVEL.

What happens when the stored procedure with `transaction B` run?

1. `transaction B` takes a lock on the entire table causing all `transaction A` to fail?

or

2. `transaction B` takes a range lock on last month purchases so that `transaction A` can complete  undisturbed?

Comment: This completely depends on your data cardinality, the queries, indexes and various other factors, there is no black & white answer.

Comment: Is transaction B also SERIALIZABLE? The level and types of locks will depend much on the available indexes and query details. Add DDL and DML for a specific case to your question. Note that conflicting locks may cause blocking but not a failure unless a deadlock occurs.

Comment: Situation is easily testable - no reason to "wonder" or "doubt". Just open two SSMS query windows to test various ways of partially executing the logic to see what happens when one starts but doesn't complete before the other starts.

Answer (score 0):

The recurring message here is that what you're asking is not only dependent on **transactions** but also dependent on a concept called **locks**.

There are different types of locks that can occur which will result in different outcomes. A row level lock only locks the specific rows needed for the query, whereas a table level lock would lock the entire table. As pointed out in the comments, which lock occurs depends on a number of factors including your table cardinality.

For example, if your table has 5,000 rows and `Transaction B` needs to modify 4,900 rows, then often times it'll request a table lock. Otherwise if your table had 1 billion rows, and `Transaction B` only needed to modify 1,000 rows, then likely it'll only request a row level lock.

In the scenario where `Transaction B` requests a table lock, it'll sit and wait being blocked by `Transaction A` until `Transaction A` finishes. It won't fail, and just happily wait its turn indefinitely to access the table. (Note this is ignoring how *distributed transactions* work, which may or may not have a timeout defined.)

In the scenario where `Transaction B` requests a row level lock, it'll immediately get access to the rows it needs and complete its transaction without having to wait on `Transaction A` (so long as it's updating different rows than what `Transaction A` is processing).

In either outcome, no error actually occurs.